# Javascript need to push or update a json object with more nested data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am wanting to ADD more nested object data to my existing object

Currently the JSON object array  ( not sure I'm saying that right)  looks like this:

```
var orderDetails = [{
  "utilityType": "Electric",
  "firstName": "ROBERT",
  "lastName": "GUERRERO",
  "utilityList": [{
        "name": "CPE",
        "type": "Electric",
        "ldcCode": "CPE",
        "accountNumberTypeName": "ESI ID"
  }],
  "program": [{
        "programId": 2090
  }]
}];
```

However, I need to modify with Javascript this JSON object data to `append` it

So I was trying to create a new nested JSON object to then `push` into the existing json object array?

```
  var newOrder = [{
      "program": {
          "accountNumberType": {
              "accountNumberTypeName": "ESI ID"
         },
      "programId": 2090
   },
 }];


   orderDetails.push(orderDetails.program.accountNumberType.accountNumberTypeName = newOrder);
```

That ends up in an error

1. Is it possible to update my existing JSON object?
2. Will a `push` work?

My fiddle of it  https://jsfiddle.net/j6L4s9mg/

I essentially want END RESULT to look like this:

```
var orderDetails = [{
  "utilityType": "Electric",
  "firstName": "ROBERT",
  "lastName": "GUERRERO",
  "utilityList": [{
    "name": "CPE",
    "type": "Electric",
    "ldcCode": "CPE",
    "accountNumberTypeName": "ESI ID"
  }],
  "program": [{
     "accountNumberType": {
        "accountNumberTypeName": "ESI ID"
    },
    "programId": 2090
  }]
}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make

```
orderDetails[0].program = newOrder[0].program;
```

[check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j6L4s9mg/1/)

Comment: So doing this =  instead of a push?

Comment: Yes, because your intention is to merge orderDetails' program with newOrder's program

Comment: I'm realizing that I don't want to overwrite existing data,  I have `"programId": 2090` already  , but i will not be supplying it and many other fields in `program`,   thus I really need to just ADD this nested `accountNumberType....`    , how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Push will work fine but the orderDetails itself is an array. So first iterate the orderDetails array and then push the code like this

```
orderDetails.program.push(newOrder.program);
```

if orderDetails is

```
var orderDetails = {
 "utilityType": "Electric",
 "firstName": "ROBERT",
 "lastName": "GUERRERO",
 "utilityList": [{
 "name": "CPE",
 "type": "Electric",
 "ldcCode": "CPE",
 "accountNumberTypeName": "ESI ID"
 }],
 "program": [{
 "programId": 2090
 }]
};
```

newOrder also is an array so iterate it again and then push. For demo I kept both as object instead of array. Just put a looping statement and you will get what you need. :)

Working demo is here - https://jsfiddle.net/vishalsrinivasan/5eLxj2bq/

Comment: Is what i have called a  json object array or what?     OP is not doing a push,  what is better?

Comment: You can use something like this 
`orderDetails[0].program.push(newOrder[0].program);`
Pushing is always a better solution compared to assigning as it will reduce the code.